# Feed a target probability distribution to the input of a NN model?

Tags: machine-learning, distributions, neural-networks, mathematical-statistics

I am trying to solve a multi class classification problem. I already have 2 known distributions of the target class . I want my Neural Network model to predict the target class based on the combination of these two distributions and also a couple of other inputs . How do i go about creating such a model ?

explanation:

For example : I want to predict the weather today of a certain town (rainy , sunny , normal) and it is known the weather depends on the past weather of two neighboring towns (and some additional factors) and the given data is in format (Town A : (rainy for 50% of the past 100 days , sunny for 25% and normal for 25%), Town B: (rainy for 20% of the past 100 days , sunny for 40% and normal for 40%)) . How can I feed this data into predicting the weather of Town C which depends on the past weather of Town A, Town B and couple other factors ?

Comment: Is this all the data that you have? If yes, there’s nothing much neural network can learn from it beyond things you can calculate from the probabilities by hand.

Answer (score 0):

The input can be a vector that includes the values for each factor  (rainy , sunny , normal)  for each town so the input could look like [50,25,25,20,40,40] for town A and B together and the expected output is the a vector with values for the rainy, sunny and normal for Town C. This only makes sense if you have many rows with Town 1, Town 2 descriptions and Town 3 weather. The input vector can be extended with other features you may have.